# How to use named selection for filtering in Vaex

Tags: python, vaex

I created 2 named selections

```
df.select(df.x => 2,name='bigger')
df.select(df.x < 2,name='smaller')
```

and it's cool, I can use the `selection` parameter so many (ie statistical) functions offer, for example

```
df.count('*',selection='bigger')
```

but is there also a way to use the named selection in a filter? Something like

```
df['bigger']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that syntax `df['bigger']` is accessing a column (or expression) in vaex that is called 'bigger'.

However, you can do: `df.filter('bigger')` and will give you a filtered dataframe.

Note that, while similar in some ways, filters and selections are a bit different, and each has its own place when using vaex.

Comment: Is it possible to filter inplace?